# How can I store licence key in server database and take that in python

Tags: python, tkinter, random, license-key

How can I store a license key database for my paid software in python and then when users has the license key the software key will check the license key in server's database and if it find ones then the software opens and then when one year is past by then the license key will expire

I have looked at some examples on the net have come to the conclusion that python is not a great programming language to build software such as this so i am going to do that in JAVA.

Comment: python is not good language for this - usually it is not problem to decompile code and get key from code or remove code which check key. Frankly, only web page on your server is safe for this because user can't have access to source code.

Comment: How do we do that like full A to Z explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as far as I know you have one possibilty to do this well with python, and that would be having a server store keys, because python code is very open so you cannot save it locally. especially storing locally that it is valid for one year will pretty easily be 'hacked', so just do so on database on a server.